# Replace in Notepad++ with unique number

Tags: notepad++

I have a following question. For example I have a file with some info:

```
<line1>**123ABC000001**</line1>
<line2>SOMETEXTHERE</line2>
<line3>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line3>
<line4>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line4>
<line5>**123ABC000001**</line1>
<line6>SOMETEXTHERE</line2>
<line7>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line3>
<line8>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line4>
<line9>**123ABC000001**</line1>
<line10>SOMETEXTHERE</line2>
<line11>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line3>
<line12>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line4>
```

and i want line1, line5, line9 to be unique numbers with increment for example:

```
<line1>**123ABC000001**</line1>
<line2>SOMETEXTHERE</line2>
<line3>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line3>
<line4>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line4>
<line5>**123ABC000002**</line1>
<line6>SOMETEXTHERE</line2>
<line7>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line3>
<line8>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line4>
<line9>**123ABC000003**</line1>
<line10>SOMETEXTHERE</line2>
<line11>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line3>
<line12>SOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERESOMETEXTHERE</line4>
```

and so long. Is there any possibility to create something in Notepad++?

Thanks

Comment: The lines you want to edit always have that format? `**numberslettersnumners**`? How they differ compared to the other lines?

Comment: The format could be any numbers, but it should be unique.

Comment: I mean, We need a way to distinguish lines 1, 5, and 9 from the others. Does the lines that you want to manipulate are always separated by 3 number of lines? Perhaps the lines you want to manipulate have some sort of text that is only present on those lines compared to the rest?